# Unix join command (on Windows) - carriage returns / line feeds inconsistency

Tags: unix, join

attempting to use the Unix join command under Windows (unxutils) and i am getting weird results.

the input files are File_1.txt and File_2.txt.  each of the lines in these files ends with the standard Windows CR/LF.

**File_1.txt**

```
Path,CurrentFileCount1,CurrentFileSize1,FileCount1 **CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\ado",1,2,3 **CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\en-US",11,22,33 **CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\msadc\en-US",111,222,333 **CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\msadc",1111,2222,3333
```

**File_2.txt**

```
Path,CurrentFileCount2,CurrentFileSize2,FileCount2 **CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\ado",4,5,6 **CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\en-US",44,55,66 **CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\msadc\en-US",444,555,666 **CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\msadc",4444,5555,6666
```

each file has 4 fields and i am joining on the first field in each file.

using the -o parameter i am omitting the last field in each file and the results are as expected with a CR/LF after each line.

**Files_joined_3_fields.txt**

```
Path,CurrentFileCount1,CurrentFileSize1,CurrentFileCount2,CurrentFileSize2 **CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\ado",1,2,4,5 **CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\en-US",11,22,44,55 **CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\msadc\en-US",111,222,444,555 **CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\msadc",1111,2222,4444,5555 **CRLF**
```

however if i include all 4 fields from either file or all 4 fields from both files i get a single CR after the 4th field.

**Files_joined_4_fields_left.txt**

```
Path,CurrentFileCount1,CurrentFileSize1,FileCount1 **CR**
,CurrentFileCount2,CurrentFileSize2 **CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\ado",1,2,3 **CR**
,4,5 **CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\en-US",11,22,33 **CR**
,44,55 **CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\msadc\en-US",111,222,333 **CR**
,444,555 **CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\msadc",1111,2222,3333,4444,555 **CRLF**
```

**Files_joined_4_fields_right.txt**

```
Path,CurrentFileCount1,CurrentFileSize1,CurrentFileCount2,CurrentFileSize2,FileCount2 **CR**
**CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\ado",1,2,4,5,6 **CR**
**CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\en-US",11,22,44,55,66 **CR**
**CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\msadc\en-US",111,222,444,555,666 **CR**
**CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\msadc",1111,2222,4444,5555,6666 **CRLF**
```

**Files_joined_4_fields_both.txt**

```
Path,CurrentFileCount1,CurrentFileSize1,FileCount1 **CR**
,CurrentFileCount2,CurrentFileSize2,FileCount2 **CR**
**CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\ado",1,2,3 **CR**
,4,5,6 **CR**
**CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\en-US",11,22,33 **CR**
,44,55,66 **CR**
**CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\msadc\en-US",111,222,333 **CR**
,444,555,666 **CR**
**CRLF**
"c:\program files\Common Files\System\msadc",1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666 **CRLF**
```

the same thing happens if i do not use the -o parameter where all fields are included.  the results is the same as what is shown in **Files_joined_4_fields_both.txt**

i know that i can use sed to get rid of these extraneous CR's but i am curious as to why they are present.

Answer (score 0):

> i know that i can use sed to get rid of these extraneous CR's but i am
>   curious as to why they are present.

Apparently this version of `join` doesn't respect the Windows line ending convention on input; it treats the CR as part of the last field, so wherever the last field of a line appears in the output, it has the CR as its last character.